# No Internet on VPN (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

Recently I setted up RRAS on my Windows Server 2012 R2.

My server has an interface to the Internet (`Ethernet`), and second interface - not connected to anything (`Ethernet 2`).

From client, I can connect to the VPN Server, but I cannot view webpages and use Internet at all. I user L2TP\IPSec with preshared key.

**Server Firewall**:

TCP (In, Out): 443, 1701, 1723.

UDP (In, Out): 500, 1701.

Here are the steps I did:
[image: Selecting VPN and NAT because I need my clients to go to the Internet]

Here I select the first one - `Ethernet` and then click on *Next*.
[image]

Here I'm setting my IP pool for private network. When I leave it dynamic, I get error `720` while connecting from client.
[image]

After that I was asked to use RADIUS, but I pointed a tick on `No`.

Then I got this:
[image]

Now, under `IPv4` I got strange IP: `192.168.192.128`. Why `128`? Also, do I need `Broadcast name resolution`?
[image]

So, at this point I can connect my client. But I don't have Internet.[image]

So I went back to the server. In Internet I found some articles about DHCP, but I don't really know what I have to set up here:
[image]
[image]

Here are my NAT properties. As you can see, `Ethernet` receive something.
[image]

Setting this tick doesn't help in both cases: `192.168.0.0` and `192.168.192.169`:
[image]

`Ethernet`, obviously, is public and NAT-enabled. `Internal` is private. Do I really need `Internal` here?
[image]

Also I tried to set up `Address Pool`, where public was my public IP and private is `192.168.192.169`. Didn't help.
[image]

**UPD 1**

Well, after some research I made it work.

I started once again and selected `Custom config`, then selected `VPN` and `NAT`. Added static IP pool, `Ethernet` adapter as DNS, WINS and DHCP. In `IPv4` I added `NAT` protocol and added `Ethernet` there. And I was able to connect to the internet from the client. **BUT!**

Just after I load webpage on the client, my Windows Server stopped to response, RDP is lost and VPN disconnected. Even VNC didn't work. I needed to restart my server, so it can work once again.

I can ping some sites, even load Google. But after Google is loaded, Windows Server stopped to respond...

Also I have this error in Event Log:
`VPN IP Addressing monitor has gone from HEALTHY state to UNHEALTHY state on 6/3/2017 at 2:19 PM on WIN-344VU98D3R. The failure heuristic IDs for state change of VPN IP Addressing are 40030001.`

What the hell is that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to install the NAT (Routing) when installing the VPN role at the beginning of the instruction...

[image]